# How do I take the title of a website and add it to an Excel spreadsheet using AppleScript + Excel

Tags: excel, applescript, workflow

I'm pretty sure this is an easy task, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

In short, I would like to use a keyboard shortcut take the title of the current page I'm on, and save it to an Excel document, basically creating a log of websites. If possible, I would like to add a link to the title that is saved in Excel.

I know how to add the Applescript as a service or workflow and such, but I can't wrap my mind around how to code this. The farthest I've gotten is grabbing the name of the website, but have no clue how to paste it to Excel, add a link to the title, then go to the next line.

Thank you for any assistance you may have.

Answer (score 0):

Try these two lines of AppleScript

```
tell first document of application "Safari" to set pageTitle to name

tell first document of application "Safari" to set pageURL to URL
```